# bash selectively copy files/folders to another location

Tags: linux, bash, shell, explode

I have a loop in my script, which iterates over an array - `myArray` and I need to do some copying of files/directories on each iteration. The array can be like this -

```
myArray=('ajax' 'style/prod_styles' `path/to/some_file.php` 'templates' 'uploadify')
```

Taking this array, for elements without a `/`, I need to copy the entire folders and their contents - e.g. `ajax`, `templates`, `uploadify`. But for those having slashes - like `style/prod_styles` (Note that there can be multiple slashes), I need to copy only the last element (e.g. for `/path/to/some/folder` I need to copy only `folder` and its contents) and in case the parent folders are not existing in the destination (e.g. `path`, `to`, `some` are the parent folders), I need to just create those folders and then copy the last element (`folder`).

Earlier I guessed it would be easy to do an explode (like PHP's `explode()`) with `/` inside the loop and then recursively start from the parent (`path` directory as per the above example) check if its child directory exists, if not create it, till we are done with the parent of the file/directory to be copied, then do the final copy.

If, however there is something simpler possible in bash to do this, please let me know.

Thanks,
Sandeepan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question, you probably don't need to use an explode-like facility to achieve what you want.

Example:

```
# dir to copy to    
DESTINATION='/path/to/copy/to/.'

# dir to copy from
SOURCE='.' 

# list of dirs to copy
myArray=('ajax' 'style/prod_styles' 'templates' 'uploadify')

# for each directory in myArray ...
for d in "${myArray[@]}"
do
    if [ -f "$d" ]; then # it this is a regular file

        # create base directory
        mkdir -p $DESTINATION/$(dirname "$d")

        # copy the file
        cp "$SOURCE/$d" $DESTINATION/$(dirname "$d")

    elif [ -d "$d" ]; then # it is a directory

        # create directory (including parent) if it doesn't exist
        # - this does nothing if directory exists
        mkdir -p "$DESTINATION/$d"

        # recursive copy
        cp -r "$SOURCE/$d/"* "$DESTINATION/$d/."

    else 

        # write warning to stderr. do nothing with this entry
        echo "WARNING: invalid entry $d." >&2

    fi
done
```

#### Update:

Updated sample code to maintains relative path within destination. So `styles/prod_styles` will be copied to `$DESTINATION/styles/prod_styles` but all other stuff within `styles/` are not copied.

Note that some additional checks need to be added if one cannot be sure that:

- path specified in `DESTINATION` exists
- not all values in `myArray` are valid directories (not files)

#### Update 2:

Example code updated to handle regular files as well as directory.

Comment: Ok, I think `mkdir -p` will do that.

Comment: better to add a few double quotes:  `"${myArray[@]}"` and `"$d"`

Comment: @Shawn +1 - this works perfect in case of directories (`/path/to/some/directory/`) but in case of files (`/path/to/some/file.php`). I get a directory `file.php` created  by the `mkdir -p "$DESTINATION/$d"` command. How do I correctly handle file just like directories.

Comment: @sandeepan I've updated the answer to check for and handle files and directories differently.

Comment: @Shawn - still not working for files because `mkdir -p $DESTINATION/$(basename "$d")` evaluates to `mkdir -p `destination/path/to/index.php` in case of `index.php`. Is there some command which returns the parent directory's path ?(e.g. returns `/path/to/some/` for `/path/to/some/file.php`)

Comment: @Sandeepan `basename "/path/to/some/file.php"` should return `/path/to/some/file`. Can't see why `mkdir -p $DESTINATION/$(basename "$d")` wouldn't work. Hmmm..

Comment: (just a hunch, but) Have you deleted the rogue `index.php` directory from the previous run?

Comment: @Shawn - `man basename` or `basename --help` says something else on my system. The example sections in both of them say `EXAMPLES - 1>basename /usr/bin/sort - Output "sort"  2>basename include/stdio.h .h - Output "stdio"`. And yes I start fresh by removing all previous files/directories from destination every time.

Comment: Opps.. sorry. haven't had my coffee. I actually meant `dirname`!! will update answer. Apologies for confusion.

Comment: If you're using bash a good alternative to calling `$(dirname "$d")` is `${d%/*}`; no dependency on an external binary and many fewer execs.

Comment: @Sorpigal. Good one! For clarity sake, I'd opt for using `dirname`. However, your approach is definitely worth considering if the solution needs to be scaled to large numbers of files and performance becomes an issue.

Comment: @Shawn: I agree, for clarity dirname is superior.

Comment: @Shawn - yes it works with `dirname`. Thank you for that. But one more correction needed in your solution. In all the places where you have used `$d` - like `cp -r "$SOURCE/$d/"* "$DESTINATION/$d/."` it should be `cp -r "$SOURCE/${allFilesFolders[$d]}/"* "$DESTINATION/${allFilesFolders[$d]}/."` because `myArray`'s values contain those things (file/folder names) and not the keys.

Comment: @Shawn - sorry, please ignore my last comment. I was iterating over keys in my code. Now your code is working correctly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear to me what you mean by "only the last element"; the `cp` command only copies the last item in a path to the destination. My guess is that you want to preserve the relative path in the destination:

```
path=style/prod_styles
dest=/path/to/some/folder

# Create same path structure
destPath="${dest}/$(dirname "$path")"
mkdir -p "${destPath}"

# copy src folder into correct place
cp -r "$path" "${destPath}"
```

Note that this also works when `path` doesn't contain slashes. In this case, `dirname` returns `.`.

If you want to use just the last part of the path (so that `style/prod_styles` becomes `prod_styles`), then you need not do anything special:

```
path=style/prod_styles
dest=/path/to/some/folder

mkdir -p "${dest}"

# copy src folder into correct place
cp -r "$path" "${dest}"
```

Comment: yes I just want to preserve the relative path in the destination and only copy the last element. Taking example of `/path/to/some/folder` again, I need to copy only `folder` and its contents and not any other files/folders that may be there inside `some` or inside `to`

Comment: Ah. In that case, you don't need to do anything. See my edits.

Comment: +1 - This works perfect in case of directories (`/path/to/some/directory/`) but in case of files (`/path/to/some/file.php`). I get a directory `file.php` created  by the `mkdir -p "$DESTINATION/$d"` command. How do I correctly handle file just like directories.

Comment: @Sandeepan: What do you get for `echo "$(dirname "/path/to/some/file.php")"`? I get `/path/to/some` so the code works. I suggest to put a `set -x` into the script so you can see what actually happens.

Comment: yes it works now with `dirname`. Accepting Shawn's answer because he provided constant and immediate support. But thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

One technique to test if a string contains a slash:

```
case "$var" in
  */*) echo "I have a slash" ;;
  *)   echo "no slash for me" ;;
esac
```

Comment: I think simply checking for `/` is not enough here, because if `/` is present I still need to confirm the existence of the directories in the path and then create them if needed. If `mkdir -p` is to be used for creating the directories, then there is no need to check for existence of `/` in the beginning because that would be an extra step.